# Kafka - max message size setting

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This is my architecture:

```
Kafka DC -> MirrorMaker -> Kafka Aggregate  
Kafka DC max.message.bytes -1 M  
Mirrormaker -> max.request.size -> 2M and Batch.size -> 1M  
Kafka Aggregate -> max.message.bytes -> 2M
```

I am still seeing message *Size Large Exceptions* on the Kafka Agg side.

Comment: Do you mean RecordTooLargeException? Could you paste the entire stack trance?

Comment: kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException:  on the Agg side. Sure will post the stack trace

Answer (score 3):

If MessageSizeTooLargeException instead of RecordTooLargeException was thrown, it means you are using the old consumer. Try to increase 'fetch.message.max.bytes' to have it be at least as large as the maximum message size.

**EDIT**: Based on the stack trace, the problem occurs when producing messages, so check broker config 'message.max.bytes' to ensure it is no less than the max message size. The default value is 1000012 bytes which is less than 1MB.

Comment: Thanks But I see the error on the destination broker logs .. Here is the exception that I get
 KafkaServer.log.3-2016-10-24 12:52:48,322 [kafka-request-handler-18] INFO  (kafka.server.KafkaApis)  - [KafkaApi-2] Closing connection due to error during produce request with correlation id 410709612 from client id producer-1 with ack=0
KafkaServer.log.3:Topic and partition to exceptions: [topic1,6] -> kafka.common.MessageSizeTooLargeException

Comment: I don't know what your comment expresses here. Did you increase 'fetch.message.max.bytes' then?

Comment: What I am saying is there is no config param fetch.message.max.bytes on Destination Kafka Broker Config. I always had a problem with Kafka Broker reporting this message and not the Mirrormaker.

Comment: It IS an error marking something wrong happened. However, because acks is set to zero, meaning the producer does not need response, the Kafka dev might think this is not a serious problem. That's why it's with INFO log level. Personally, I agree that this should be at least at WARN level.

Comment: Is there anyway I can debug this ? Since I am getting this error in KafkaApi Class -> produceResponseCallback method . Thanks a ton in advance